# SQL Server Backup/Restore IO performance on Azure VM

Tags: sql-server, performance, restore, azure-vm

We are currently experiencing an issue where the IO performance of our SQL Server running on an Azure VM isn't quite up to snuff.

We are running a Azure VM (Standard DS2). This one has a 127 GB SSD C: drive throttled at 64 MB/s. We added an extra drive to this VM because we believe it should be able to perform faster than the limited 64 MB/s.

When doing copy operations (using AZCopy) to the newly added & faster F: drive we can see that the IO speeds are a lot higher. However, when restoring a database backup from this new & fast F: drive to a location on that same drive we're still getting throttled at 64MB/s.

We've contacted Microsoft about this but up until now they were unable to provide a proper explanation. Anyone has any experience with this?

Attached you'll find a screenshot of the performance monitor during the restore, showing that the read & write operations are only happening on the new F: drive, while showing a fairly stable 64MB/s.

[image: Performance monitor during restore of database]

Comment: The new drive that was added, was that from the same storage account ?

Comment: The new drive is a Premium (SSD). Normally this one should get around 200 MB/s throughput.

Comment: How many disks does that drive have ?

Comment: @karun10 As far as I know, just this one F drive.

Comment: Ok and when you face these throttling, is your VM getting rebooted ?

Comment: You're restoring a file on the same drive as the backup? Then your throughput would be cut in half, yes.

Comment: @RandolphWest I can see why it would make sense that way, but as the screenshot shows it's actually not like that.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question. You are asking why the disk is hitting the throttled limit that MS has for a Standard DS2 server? Documentation shows for that server size the max uncached throughput is 6400 IOPS and 64 MBps.